# How to export all the defects linked to a ticket in JIRA?

Tags: export, jira, defects

I am trying to export all the defects and requirements linked (Relates TO) to a release ticket in JIRA. However, when I use the export option in the release ticket, it only exports the ticket id, status and summary of the linked items. I want a way to export all the information of the linked tickets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JQL advanced native search feature in JIRA and enter the following query:

```
issue in linkedIssues(TICKET-123)
```

You configure the seach page with columns that you need and export the content as Excel/csv.

To use JQL advanced search, go to menu Issues -> Search for Issues. Then click on Advanced.